# Horizontally center entire contents of page

Tags: css, responsive-design, centering

I am trying to horizontally center everything on my page when it is on a smaller screen.

Currently everything aligns right;

Here is my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1038px) {
.wrapper{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

I also tried `margin: 0 auto;` to no avail. `text-align:center;` will only change the text inside of their divs.

The page I am working on is http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/

Please let me know if you can help and thank you!

Comment: You need to add more 'responsiveness' to your block elements. They just stop fitting the narrower container and fall down, but their widths remain almost the same.

Comment: That's the idea. I want them all to stay the same width and move below the others. The client doesn't want the elements to get wider. What I need to to get them all to center the don't line up on the left.

Comment: In that case you have to remove the floats and set `margin: 0 auto` on the smaller widths' css.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at any of these to and Responsiveness to your site elements.  Although it looks like you already have something like this going on.

There is a possibility you will have to come up with something specific for your purposes.  But using one of these and seeing how they do it would be a good starting point for cooking up your own solution.

- Skeleton: http://www.getskeleton.com/ (see Grid)
- Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html (see Scaffolding)
- Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/ (see The Grid)

Comment: These may work but I really don't want to go back and restructure the whole site. We are trying to launch in a day to two. Is there a way to just make every element in the wrapper center with CSS?

Comment: The answer is no.  There is no `.wrapper * { margin: 0 auto; }` magic hack.  You will need to get a better understanding of web development, particularly Responsive Design.  As that seems to be what you want.  There are a lot of good resources on the web to learn Responsive Web Design.  And even better ones available in good old analog book form.  There is no shortcut on this one my friend.  Stick to it and you will get there.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
 #content{
   width: 1038px 
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   padding: 10px;   //paddig might make this width a but more so you might need narrow that
   text-aling: center;
 }
```

I don't know for sure if i did that text aling right but something like that could help

Answer (score -2):

You can use a table like this:

```
<table width="1038px" align="center">
   <tr>
       <td>
          your main content
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I really don't want to go back to using a table in my HTML. Isn't there a way to do it with CSS?

Comment: I broke down and actually tried this but it didn't work at all.

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting tables for layout and using soon to be defunct and mostly unused attributes like `align`.